# jqplot bar chart multiple series on one datapoint

Tags: javascript, canvas, jqplot

I'm trying to get a `jqplot` chart to display a bunch of data in different colored bars with a key on the right, but the scaling doesn't seem to work properly.  My data looks like this:

```
data:[[1.03],[1.02],[1.05],[1.02],[1.011]],
labels:["Imperial Stout","Lager","Porter","Etc","etc"],
```

I can try to let it auto scale, and it cuts off half of the bars like this: [image: Bars cut off on the left][(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/VeA7s/10/)

I tried setting the axis scale from 0.8 to 1.2, but it clusters all of the bars in the center leaving a ton of empty space on the chart like this:[image: Bars clustered in center]  [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/VeA7s/9/)

Is there a way to get this to display correctly?

I can't put them in one series because the legend just labels that as "Series 1".

Comment: The jsfiddles that you provided do not work - at all - for me, I get 'NetworkError: 403 Forbidden' when trying to load the various libraries.

Comment: Ok, I updated it to point to the versions from bitbucket.  These must be a different version because they broke the legend, but that's not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following option to `xaxis` :

`renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,`

and `tickOptions` could be set to `show: false` if you don't want an extraneous tickmark under the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was configuring the `xaxis` as follows:

```
xaxis: {
    label: input.xaxis,
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks: ['']
},
```

By default, the axis rendered is a `$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer`, which tries to render a numeric axis, hence the problems you were having.

Interestingly, I also had to set `ticks` as I did because without it I was getting a single tick value of 1 displayed on the x-axis and I couldn't otherwise get rid of it.